# Why do some parts of the books of Kings not appear in the books of Chronicles?

Tags: contradiction, 2-kings, 2-chronicles

> II Kings 14:28 KJV — Now the rest of the acts of Jeroboam, and all
>   that he did, and his might, how he warred, and how he
>   recovered Damascus, and Hamath, which belonged to Judah,
>   for Israel, **are they not written in the book of chronicles of the
>   kings of Israel?**

I searched for Jeroboam son of Joash in the books of Chronicles without success. If the bold letters are true, a detailed account of the recovery of Damascus and Hamath should be in either I Chronicles or II Chronicles.

Was some part of I & II Chronicles lost? Or are they originally a
part of a larger, more comprehensive document called the
"book of chronicles of the kings of Israel"?

If the "book of chronicles" in II Kings 14:28 refers to II
Chronicles, the original scribes seemed to have made a mistake because
Jeroboam son of Joash does not appear in II Chronicles.
Chronologically, he should be mentioned somewhere around II
Chronicles 25 & 26. However, it may be that I have failed to read a passage
of the books of Chronicles which actually explains II Kings
14:28. But even the commentaries and cross references seem
to evade this question. How come?

Comment: Simple: the books of 1 & 2 Chronicles are the Chronicles of the Kings of *Judah*, not *Israel*.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ I am referring to the lesser known Jeroboam. II Kings 14:23 — "In the fifteenth year of Amaziah the son of Joash king of Judah **Jeroboam the son of Joash king of Israel began to reign in Samaria**, and reigned forty and one years." He was also the king during the time of prophet Hosea: Hosea 1:1 — "The word of the Lord that came unto Hosea, the son of Beeri, in the days of Uzziah, Jotham, Ahaz, and Hezekiah, kings of Judah, and **in the days of Jeroboam the son of Joash, king of Israel.**"

Comment: @curiousdannii Would I be able to find that somewhere? Or is the chronicles of the kings of Israel not known to us?

Comment: @JohnDoeThePseudoguy - sorry, I can't read.

Comment: @JohnDoeThePseudoguy They haven't survived until now unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Book of Kings (*1 Kings* and *2 Kings* were originally a single book that was eventually split because of its length) talks of the book of chronicles of the kings of Israel, it could not be referring the the Book we know as *Chronicles* (*1 Chronicles* and *2 Chronicles*) because *Chronicles* was written centuries later.

Most critical scholars attribute the Book of Kings to an anonymous author now known as the Deuteronomist, who wrote during the seventh-century-BCE reign of King Josiah of Judah. The Book of Chronicles, along with the Books of Ezra and Nehemiah form an integrated block of text with a unity of style and content, allowing us to date *Chronicles* to the period following the Babylonian Exile - centuries after the Deuteronomic History was written.

The Books we know as *1 and 2 Chronicles* are not the now-lost books of chronicles of the kings of Israel and Judah, to which The Book of Kings refers. *Chronicles* appears to make use of the earlier Books of Kings, as well as other sources, occasionally altering or omitting some material from *1 and 2 Kings*.  John Romer says, in *[Testament: the Bible and History](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568524897)*, the difference in attitude between the Deuteronomist and the Chronicler is often seen as representing two different factions among the returning Jews.